# Multiple Relay fragments in one React component?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, relay, relaymodern

This is example from the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/fragment-container.html). The problem is, what if I also need some other data in my TodoItem component that is completely on a different location in the data graph and can't come through Todo->TodoItem chain.

```
class TodoItem extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const item = this.props.data;

  }
}
module.exports = createFragmentContainer(
  TodoItem,
  graphql`
    fragment TodoItem on Todo {
      text
      isComplete
    }
  `,
);
```

It seems that Relay/GraphQL demands that the view is composed in the same hierarchy as the data model. Is there a way for a component to access other fragments? I don't know, something like this:

```
module.exports = createFragmentContainer(
  TodoItem,
  graphql`
    fragment TodoItem on Todo {
      text
      isComplete
    }
  `,
  graphql`
    fragment FriendItem on Friends {
      name
    }
  `,
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's what you want, (I'm also just starting with relay) but you can specify different fragments using [keys](https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/en/fragment-container.html#defining-containers) in the `createFragmentContainer` function:

Fragmentcontainer:

```
export default createFragmentContainer(TodoItem, {
  todo: graphql`
    fragment TodoItem_todo on Todo {
      text
      isComplete
    }
  `,
  friend: graphql`
    fragment FriendItem_friend on Friends {
      name
    }
  `,
});
```

And then in your `queryRenderer` something like this:

```
query={graphql`
    query AppQuery {
        todos {
            ...TodoItem_todo
        }
        friends {
            ...FriendItem_friend
        }
    }
`}
```

Comment: This seems like exactly what I want. Have you tested it?

Comment: not with the same items, but with a similar data structure. works perfect